# Como adicionar valores de um array em outro de forma inversa?

Tags: java

Ler um vetor D de 10 elementos. Criar um vetor E, com todos os elementos de D na ordem
inversa, ou seja, o último elemento passará a ser o primeiro, o penúltimo será o segundo e assim
por diante. Escrever todo o vetor D e todo o vetor E. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar ?
Um dos códigos que tentei:

```
int v[]=new int[3];
int z[]=new int[3]; 
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    v[i]=dado.nextInt();
}   
for (int i = z.length ; i >= 0; i++) {  
    z[i]=v[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(z[i]);
}
```

Comment: E qual é sua duvida perante o exercicio?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo adicionar osa valores do vetor v no z inversamente, poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo:

```
int[] D = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

int[] E = new int[D.length];

int j = D.length - 1;


for(int i = 0; i < D.length; i++){

      E[j] = D[i]; // i começa em 0 e j começa em 9

      j--;

}
```

Qualquer duvida disponha

Comment: Por favor, não utilize desnecessariamente formatação de destaque no texto. Percebi que em todas as suas respostas você tentou usar destaque com o caracter `#`.